# Changing Compiler Output Locations in Project Options for Indy Package corrupts its DPK file

Tags: delphi, indy

Using Delphi 10.3... I downloaded the latest Indy files and its `IndySystem260.dpk` file looks like this:

```
package IndySystem260;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO OFF}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES ON}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE DEBUG}
{$DEFINE VER330}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$DESCRIPTION 'Indy 10 System'}
{$RUNONLY}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

// RLebeau: cannot use IdCompilerDefines.inc here!

{$DEFINE HAS_PKG_RTL}
{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
  {$IFDEF IOS}
    // there is no RTL package available for iOS
    {$UNDEF HAS_PKG_RTL}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF HAS_PKG_RTL}
requires
  rtl;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFNDEF WINDOWS}
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    {$DEFINE WINDOWS}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}

contains
  IdAntiFreezeBase in 'IdAntiFreezeBase.pas',
  IdBaseComponent in 'IdBaseComponent.pas',
  IdCTypes in 'IdCTypes.pas',
  IdComponent in 'IdComponent.pas',
  IdException in 'IdException.pas',
  IdGlobal in 'IdGlobal.pas',
  IdIDN in 'IdIDN.pas',
  IdResourceStrings in 'IdResourceStrings.pas',
  {$IFNDEF WINDOWS}
  IdResourceStringsUnix in 'IdResourceStringsUnix.pas',
  IdResourceStringsVCLPosix in 'IdResourceStringsVCLPosix.pas',
  {$ENDIF}
  IdStack in 'IdStack.pas',
  IdStackBSDBase in 'IdStackBSDBase.pas',
  IdStackConsts in 'IdStackConsts.pas',
  {$IFDEF WINDOWS}
  IdStackWindows in 'IdStackWindows.pas',
  {$ELSE}
  IdStackVCLPosix in 'IdStackVCLPosix.pas',
  {$ENDIF}
  IdStream in 'IdStream.pas',
  IdStreamVCL in 'IdStreamVCL.pas',
  IdStruct in 'IdStruct.pas',
  {$IFDEF WINDOWS}
  IdWinsock2 in 'IdWinsock2.pas',
  IdWship6 in 'IdWship6.pas'
  {$ELSE}
  IdVCLPosixSupplemental in 'IdVCLPosixSupplemental.pas'
  {$ENDIF}
  ;

end.
```

As soon as I change `Project Options > Building > Delphi Compiler > DCP output directory` to `..\..\..\Delphi 10.3\DCP\$(Platform)\$(Config)` the DPK is changed to:

```
package IndySystem260;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO OFF}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES ON}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE DEBUG}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$DESCRIPTION 'Indy 10 System'}
{$RUNONLY}
{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}

rrequires
  rtl;

$contains
  IdAntiFreezeBase in 'IdAntiFreezeBase.pas',
  IdBaseComponent in 'IdBaseComponent.pas',
  IdCTypes in 'IdCTypes.pas',
  IdComponent in 'IdComponent.pas',
  IdException in 'IdException.pas',
  IdGlobal in 'IdGlobal.pas',
  IdIDN in 'IdIDN.pas',
  IdResourceStrings in 'IdResourceStrings.pas',
  IdStack in 'IdStack.pas',
  IdStackBSDBase in 'IdStackBSDBase.pas',
  IdStackConsts in 'IdStackConsts.pas',
  IdStackWindows in 'IdStackWindows.pas',
  IdStream in 'IdStream.pas',
  IdStreamVCL in 'IdStreamVCL.pas',
  IdStruct in 'IdStruct.pas',
  IdWinsock2 in 'IdWinsock2.pas',
  IdWship6 in 'IdWship6.pas' {$ENDIF};

d.
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Can it be prevented without doing manual edits to the DPK file? It is something I noticed in XE3 as well.

I noticed the following on the Indy instructions page:

> Note for Cross-Platform compiling:
>
> The current Indy 10 package projects are set for Windows compilations.
> The IndySystem and IndyProtocols packages do have a few
> platform-specific units in them, which are conditionally compiled via
> IFDEF statements in the DPK files.  This is fine for command-line
> compilations, but the IDE usually doesn't handle IFDEFs in DPK files
> very well, and this can also cause an associated DPROJ file to be out
> of sync with its DPK file. So this may lead to issues if you want to
> compile Indy 10 via the IDE for non-Windows platforms (in Delphi
> versions that support this). You might need to edit the IndySystem
> project to remove the IFDEFs and replace the IdStackWindows,
> IdWinsock2, and IdWship6 units with the IdStackVCLPosix and
> IdVCLPosixSupplemental units instead, and then edit the IndyProtocols
> project to remove the IFDEFs and the IdAuthenticationSSPI and IdSSPI
> units.  Perhaps in a future release, we will try to automate/cleanup
> this better.

It may say `So this may lead to issues if you want to compile Indy 10 via the IDE for non-Windows platforms` but I suspect I will have to paste the DPK code back after changing the Options.

Comment: Conditional Defines in DPR/DPK don't play well in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

That looks more like the "well-known" issue with mixed line breaks.
Probably the original file has unix endings and the change in the IDE converts some lines to PC endings.

Comment: May be, but whatever ist is, as soon as you edit the project options for that package the IDE will mess up that package code completely.

Comment: Interestingly the Indy DPK only has LineFeeds but after replacing them with CarraigeReturn + LineFeeds it still had the issue so I am assuming this issue to be "IDE does not play nice with Conditional Defines"

Comment: The CR+LF does at least prevent the incorrect additional `r` in front of the `requires` clause and also the `$` in front of `contains`